# Колонка с вертикальным скроолом, внутри карточки, у карточек есть попапы - показать эти попапы за границами колонки

Tags: javascript, css, angular

```css
.col {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: green;
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: silver;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.drop {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10%;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 33;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="drop">popup</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

вот код который нужно заставить работать.
Есть колонка с вертикальным скролом.
Внутри колонки карточки (по сути как в трело).
Внутри карточек есть всплывающие попапы.

проблема в том что бы иметь и скрол, и что бы попапы были привязаны к карточке как оно там сейчас, но что бы они были видны за границами колонки со скролом.

---

Нашлось решение. Библиотека popper.js отлично решила данную проблему

Comment: "они были видны за границами колонки со скролом" - это чтобы были видны на всю ширину и высоту или просто в поверхности этого блока?

Comment: если с этого класа: .col  убрать:  overflow-x: hidden;   overflow-y: auto; то сразу станеет понятно как должны быть видны попапы. Но при этом надо как то скохранить возможность скрола в колонке.

Comment: Боюсь, такое можно сделать только с `position:absolute`, добавлять элемент на `body` и устанавливать каждому `popup` положение в пикселях через `js`.